# I cannot click on my Navigator menu?

Tags: java, android, stream, navigation

I have a really interesting problem with my Navigator menu. I have no idea why... But I cant click on any item from my menu,  I really want to say I can't click on any item. I've try to make a new project witch already have Navigation Drawer Activity, of course it works.. but when I've try to copy that code and put on mine.. I have the same problem and vice versa, I've try to put my code into a new project with Navigation Drawer Activity, but again.

Here it's my Main Activity

```
package radiofm.arabel;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.IOException;

import static android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ImageButton id_play,id_pause;

    private Button btn;
    private boolean playPause;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean initialStage = true;
    Boolean prepared = false;

    String AudioRd ="http://arabelfm.ice.infomaniak.ch/arabelprodcastfm.mp3";

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView=null;
    Toolbar toolbar =null;



    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Log.d("myTag", "This is my toolbar");


        id_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.id_play);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        id_play.setEnabled(true);
        id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        id_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!playPause) {
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Myservice.class));
                    Log.e("start", "start radio");

                    playPause = true;

                } else {
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Myservice.class));
                    Log.e("stop", "start radio");

                    playPause = false;
                }
            }
        });




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_alarm) {
            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_Alarm.class);
            startActivity(goToNextActivity);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_aaaaa) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I see a couple things that look off to me from your code above. You are making Fragment Transaction a class level variable, but those are typically new per transaction, but this is not likely relevant to your issue, just mentioning.

Then when your nav item selected is fired you are launching a new activity, but you are not sharing that code. When you are using a nav drawer you typically just swap out fragments from a placeholder id in the main activity nav drawer fragment area.

Here is an example Activity with the drawer layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable name="activity" type="com.appstudio35.activities.HomeActivity"/>
    <variable name="isLegalSelected" type="boolean"/>
</data>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- FrameLayout is used to insert fragments to display -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragPlaceholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
                android:id="@+id/navHeader"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLegal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/am_text_size_18"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="@{activity::btnLegal_onClick}"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:textColor="@{isLegalSelected ? @color/white : @color/text_color_dark_gray}"
                android:background="@{isLegalSelected ? @color/colorPrimary : @color/white}"
                tools:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                tools:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Legal"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/lstMenuItems"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtLegal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/navHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:rcvInterface="@{activity}"
                app:rcvList="@{activity.getDrawerItemList()}"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I often make a BaseActivity for my Main and others and will include a swapFragment routine so it is shared like:

```
    protected void swapFragment(BaseFragment fragment, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (fragment.isVisible()) {
        return;

    }

    A35Log.v(TAG, "swapFragment( " + fragment.getClass().getSimpleName() + " )");
    Bundle currentFragBundle = fragment.getArguments();
    if (currentFragBundle == null && bundle != null) {
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    } else if (bundle != null) {
        fragment.getArguments().putAll(bundle);

    }


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    //Make sure the requested fragment isn't already on the screen before adding it
    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
        if (fragment.isHidden()) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();

        }

        A35Log.v(TAG, "Fragment was hidden, so removeFullScreen instead of replace");
        return;

    }

    mSelectedFragment = fragment;
    A35Log.v(TAG, "Replacing Active Fragment with " + fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragPlaceholder, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Of course I'm using DataBinding so the way it is wired up is a little different, but hopefully this points you to your issue. I'm guessing it is a Z index issue so reviewing your layout file will probably reveal the answer.

If it does not, please provide your sample project or at least your xml layout file if possible to look at. As this is typically an issue of an overlay blocking the touch and it can be caused by any number of things. You could have put your layout out of order so the Z index puts the drawer under the content instead of in front of it. If that happens your layout will pass the touch to the content instead of the drawer. So check that as well.